# Calculate width in road line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro

[image]I have Road feature class [Polyline]

How can we calculate road width between two parallel lines in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?

I don’t want to measure roads width by manually?

I have road feature class which in line, just i want to maesure width between two parallel line, And i dont want to do manually.

Is that possible we can measure width of road segments with any tool in Arcgis or Arcgis Pro

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the data?

Comment: You could try extracting vertices of one line, then calculate the distance of said vertices to the nearest point on the other line.

Comment: Technically, a line doesn't have width, only length. You can calculate a *distance* between lines, and line symbolization has a width property (which often exceeds a the actual width of the feature so symbolized), but without further context, your meaning is unclear. Please [Edit] the Question.

Answer (score 1):

I split kerb lines into 20m segments and run Generate Near table between itself, limiting number of neighbors to three:

[image]

After that I joined selected records (>0) to segments. Result makes sense:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, But my concern is how to measure width between two parallel line .

Comment: So the lines on my picture are not parallel enough?

Comment: Yes, your shared picture is enough to understand. Actually i have road feature class and spot height feature class. while i am running near tool i did not get any relevant values.

Comment: Wrong tool. Run correct one, see post, between sample points and kerbs, limit to 2 nearest. Summarise results by in_fid. Same principle